# mounting CIFS just hangs no verbose output

Tags: samba, mount, cifs

I unmounted our shared drive in order to debug some immutable files and it's not allowing a mount back (even after a reboot and the entry has been there for years in the fstab file). I'm trying to do this manually and have my process flow listed below:

To mount the device:

```
mount -t cifs //xxx.xxx/storage/Public_WWW /data/www/dynamic.xxx.xxx.ca/ --verbose -o credentials=/etc/samba/mha.cred
```

This simply just hangs an provides no error output. But when I look at the logs:

When I look at the samba logs, I am getting the following error messages:

```
  kerberos_kinit_password XXX-PUBLIC1$@XXX.LOCAL failed: Preauthentication failed
[2018/07/11 14:06:46.452928,  0] libads/kerberos_util.c:101(ads_kinit_password)
  kerberos_kinit_password XXX-PUBLIC1$@XXX.LOCAL failed: Preauthentication failed
[2018/07/11 14:07:54.499816,  0] libads/kerberos_util.c:101(ads_kinit_password)
  kerberos_kinit_password XXX-PUBLIC1$@XXX.LOCAL failed: Preauthentication failed
```

The only thing I can think of is that there was a change in password or username that I somehow missed? Spent a lot of time on this today and was hoping someone might have a quick answer for me.

Comment: That means that either the kerberos ticket has expired or the password has changed. You'll have to check the password for the domain user and/or if your Linux box is joined to the domain, unjoin and rejoin it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see if there are any time differences between your cifs client and server systems. Kerberos pre-authentication uses timestamps. If there is more than a few seconds difference pre-authentication fails.